# Why am I getting this javascript error when I'm doing my Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, json

I have valid json according to jsonlint.com

In my javascript, I do this:

```
var params = JSON.parse('{{ all_params_in_json }}');
```

And I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
(anonymous function)
```

Why? My json is valid.  I'm using the standard json2 library.

My json is this:

```
{
    "browser_location": "Sausalito",
    "browser_distance": 5,
    "users_who_voted": [

    ],
    "author": {
        "username": "swnn",
        "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
        "first_name": "feli",
        "last_name": "twan",
        "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
        "is_active": true,
        "is_superuser": false,
        "is_staff": false,
        "last_login": 1295410796.0,
        "location": "San Francisco",
        "fullname": "twan Chan",
        "id": 1,
        "date_joined": 1293678904.0
    },
    "total_views": 227,
    "comments": [
        {
            "body": "sdfasdf",
            "created_at": 1295317816.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "sdfasdfasd",
            "created_at": 1295317900.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "sdasdasD",
            "created_at": 1295323153.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "The picture in this submission is not accurate",
            "created_at": 1295325473.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "This submission is not useful to me.",
            "created_at": 1295325491.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "lcokc",
            "created_at": 1295344958.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "gagaga",
            "created_at": 1295345040.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "wwwww",
            "created_at": 1295345084.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "sadfasdfasdf",
            "created_at": 1295345136.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "asdasdf",
            "created_at": 1295345253.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "sdfasdfasd",
            "created_at": 1295345279.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "asdfasdf",
            "created_at": 1295345358.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "foxed",
            "created_at": 1295345790.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "Is this really the right thing? I mean...after thinking about it. ist's just not very cool",
            "created_at": 1295345827.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "s this really the right thing? I mean...after thinking about it. ist's just not very cool",
            "created_at": 1295345871.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "his song really suck.s",
            "created_at": 1295346108.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "asdfasdf",
            "created_at": 1295383689.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "asdfasdf",
            "created_at": 1295410874.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        },
        {
            "body": "Is this all right?",
            "created_at": 1295411376.0,
            "user": {
                "username": "swnn",
                "bio": "I'm the CEO at Twitter.  Prior to Twitter, I cofounded FeedBurner (acquired by Google). I'm an investor and Advisor in a few start-ups including about.me.\r\n \r\nI used to perform with Chicago\u2019s Annoyance Theater and at various comedy festivals in Edinburgh, Montreal and other distant lands. I recently left the cold winters of Chicago for Marin County's sunshine.",
                "first_name": "feli",
                "last_name": "twan",
                "avatar_url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/937ypvlchrd2e5z1a0sq",
                "is_active": true,
                "is_superuser": false,
                "is_staff": false,
                "last_login": 1295410796.0,
                "location": "San Francisco",
                "fullname": "twan Chan",
                "id": 1,
                "date_joined": 1293678904.0
            }
        }
    ],
    "initial_vote": 0,
    "browser_lat": 37.848800659179688,
    "post": {
        "ip": "174.129.251.48",
        "thumb_500x500": {
            "url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/bv2814ghmd",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 351
        },
        "date": 1295154531.334044,
        "thumb_original": {
            "url": "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5249/5336976806_481943d486_b.jpg",
            "width": 779,
            "height": 548
        },
        "total_views": 227,
        "thumb_230x480": {
            "url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/4e7h95rt3f",
            "width": 230,
            "height": 480
        },
        "test_set": "g2",
        "title": "Maybe. . .we were supposed to meet the wrong people before meeting the right one so that, when we finally meet the right person, we will know how to be grateful for that gift ...",
        "stamp": "bf305695ca51b5390dc0c2f34c074215",
        "pop_score": 241.59687499999995,
        "thumb_640x640": {
            "url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/4q15bsgmt2",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 450
        },
        "image_direction": "landscape",
        "author_username": "swnn",
        "thumb_230x230": {
            "url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/x0dq7gzb4f",
            "width": 230,
            "height": 230
        },
        "description": "sooc with Shana Rae overlay ....",
        "top_score": 0.90000000000000002,
        "active": true,
        "original_file": "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5249/5336976806_481943d486_b.jpg",
        "loc_utm": [
            500000.0,
            6317527.4506855672
        ],
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "4d327d658aad6919be0000d5"
        },
        "sizes": [
            {
                "url": "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5249/5336976806_481943d486_b.jpg",
                "width": 779,
                "height": 548
            },
            {
                "url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/4q15bsgmt2",
                "width": 640,
                "height": 450
            },
            {
                "url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/bv2814ghmd",
                "width": 500,
                "height": 351
            },
            {
                "url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/x0dq7gzb4f",
                "width": 230,
                "height": 230
            },
            {
                "url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/4e7h95rt3f",
                "width": 230,
                "height": 480
            },
            {
                "url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/g1pmqk7r6y",
                "width": 480,
                "height": 230
            }
        ],
        "loc_latlong": [
            57.0,
            -99.0
        ],
        "thumb_480x230": {
            "url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/g1pmqk7r6y",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 230
        },
        "processed": true,
        "author_id": 1,
        "content_id": 13259,
        "thumb_500x500_low": {
            "url": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabletest/oznumyqve7",
            "width": 500,
            "quality": 4,
            "height": 351
        }
    },
    "browser_long": -122.53489685058594,
    "pos_votes_count": 0
}
```

Comment: Can you use Firebug, set a breakpoint here, and be sure what you've got in quotes is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do:

```
var params = JSON.parse('{{ all_params_in_json|escapejs }}');
```

Otherwise e.g ' char inside `all_params_in_json` variable terminates string and all hell breaks loose.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you use invalid characters for label's inside the JSON. Check this, it may be browser-dependent what's legal or not.

Comment: Can you check my json to see what incorrect characters I have? (That json is valid)

Comment: Don't see any problems there. How did you really provide the JSON to JSON.parse()? The string contains characters that will cause an error(the ' , see Tomasz' answer, also line-breaks will cause errors), if you do it like posted in your question.